# Why is this FULL JOIN not working?

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

Suppose I have this table in my SQL Server DB:

```
Date     Col_A    Col_B    Col_C    ...
Day1     1        2        3    ....
Day1     2        3        4    ....
Day1     3        4        5    ....
Day2     1        2        3    ....
Day2     2        3        4    ....
Day2     5        6        7    ....
Day2     6        7        8    ....
```

And I want to do a full outer join of the table against itself based upon `Col_A`, `Col_B` & `Col_C` to get something looking as follows:

```
Date     Col_A    Col_B    Col_C    ...  Date   Col_A    Col_B    Col_C   ....
Day1     1        2        3    ....     Day2     1        2        3    ....
Day1     2        3        4    ....     Day2     2        3        4    ....
Day1     3        4        5    ....     NULL    NULL    NULL     NULL  ..NULL..
NULL    NULL    NULL     NULL ..NULL..   Day2     5        6        7    ....
NULL    NULL    NULL     NULL ..NULL..   Day2     6        7        8    ....
```

I figured this SQL would do it:

```
SELECT * FROM
   (Select * from MyTable where Date = 'Day1') T1
FULL OUTER JOIN 
   (Select * from MyTable where Date = 'Day2') T2
ON 
   T1.Col_A = T2.Col_A
  AND
   T1.Col_B = T2.Col_B
  AND
   T1.Col_C = T2.Col_C
```

But this is only returning rows where T1 is full and T2 has `NULLS`, not the full join.

What am I doing wrong and how can I fix this??
Also, is there a better way to get this kind of record set than joining a table onto itself and just changing the date parameter??

Thanks!!!

Comment: Are there actually any rows on your table for 'Day 2'?

Comment: @Lamak - There are - as in the example.

Comment: As an update, it must have been a problem with some small typing quirk - I re-wrote the query and it worked... For anyone that is looking at this question, the query posted will do the trick. Sorry and thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your join looking good, try something like this to be sure (name all columns properly):

```
select
    isnull(T1.Col_A, T2.Col_A) as Col_A,
    isnull(T1.Col_B, T2.Col_B) as Col_B,
    isnull(T1.Col_A, T2.Col_C) as Col_C,
    T1.Date as Date1,
    T2.Date as Date2
from (select * from MyTable where Date = 'Day1') as T1
    full outer join (select * from MyTable where Date = 'Day2') as T2 on 
       T1.Col_A = T2.Col_A and T1.Col_B = T2.Col_B and T1.Col_C = T2.Col_C
order by 1, 2, 3
```

Comment: Firstly, thanks for your reply and I don't know why someone down-voted it... BUT, I will say that for my situation, it doesn't work since I actually want the nulls where the date is missing, not overwritten data... Any ideas??

Comment: Have you tried to do `t2 left outer join t1` to see if you have any corresponding data in T2? It looks like you overlooked something, query looks fine and works in sqlfiddle - http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/7a886/3, but I had to name columns because SQLFiddle doesn't show columns with identical names. I think that may be you have similar issue.

Comment: I **HATE** to be that guy, but I just re-wrote the query from the start and it worked!! - SO SORRY I made you work on this for nothing!! Since you were the only person that replied, I'll award you the answer!! SORRY and thank you for your help!!!